# How to triangulate a room of obstacles?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, triangulation

I'd like to triangulate a room full of polygonal obstacles.

I'm particularly looking for an **easy algorithm to implement** as I'm testing other functionality at the moment. Efficiency (given it can handle a few 10s of vertices within a minute) and 'quality' of the triangles won't be a consideration. Right now my thought is to loop through each vertex, checking for other vertices which it can connect to without crossing previously made connections. Are there simpler solutions or any flaws to this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can triangulate all vertexes and then remove the longest edges similar to alpha shapes.  You can look for an example at my homepage:http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use a constrained triangulation, adding all the polygon edges as constraints. Then you simply need to mark the domains starting from outside of the room.

If you're looking for a C++ implementation, you can have a look at the [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org) and in particular to [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Subsection_2D_Triangulations_Constrained_Delaunay_Example) that is doing what you want.